# using wordpress login details for other website / application / forum?

Tags: plugins, database, login, forum

I'm new here, & I need help of you experts.

here is my request/question:

I have a wordpress website: http://seriesratings.com
and a Forum (application on host): http://seriesratings.com/forum

How can we use same login details or sync database of site & application? So users don't have to signup on both. For Instance, If they have account on site they can use the same login details for forum also.

Now they have to sign up differently for both.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin !

https://wordpress.org/plugins/smf2wp/

SMF2WP is a simple one way bridge from Simple Machine Forum to WordPress. This means, this one uses databases of SMF Forum and sync to WP database every time a user performs log-in action in both WP and SMF.